# latexdiff is changing the codification

Tags: latexdiff

When I run latexdiff it changes the codification of my TEX files from utf8 to ISO (I can see at the bottom of Texstudio) 
And replaces the characters with accents (á,é,í,ó,ú) by things like (Ã­a, Ã³,Ãº.. and others like hidden characters between Ã­a.

Original Tex

```
Con base a lo anterior, en el presente trabajo, se propone desarrollar un FES que en conjunto con una \textbf{Unidad de medición inercial (IMU)}  formen un control de lazo cerrado para estimular y mantener una articulación en la orientación deseada. Además, aprovechando la reducción de tamaño y consumo de la electrónica actual, se busca la creación de un sistema portable e inalámbrico que pueda a futuro formar parte de un sistema más complejo de varios FES.

%TODO: Está bien poner los acrónimos en negritas o lo hago en itálicas?

%Esta mejora, incorporada a los sistemas actuales, buscaría reducir la dependencia de la andadera, al detectar eventos de desequilibrio del sujeto y efectuar acciones de control sobe los músculos para estabilizar nuevamente su posición en pie, para detectar estos eventos de desequilibrio, se dotará al sistema de un lazo de retroalimentación de la posición del sujeto.

%La validación del sistema, se hará en sujetos sanos, sin SCI, de los cuales, conectados al sistema, en una posición de pie, se registrarán los casos positivos donde el sistema fue capaz de re-estabilizarlos después de haber sido sometidos a una fuerza que los saque de equilibrio.

Finalmente se validará el sistema a través de la inducción de un ángulo en la rodilla, donde se evaluará la capacidad del sistema para producir y mantener la orientación preestablecida.
```

The  Diff file

```
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{En el presente trabajo, se propone desarrollar un sistema de estadÃ­a }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{Se sabe que hay mÃºsculos que son fundamentales para mantener una posiciÃ³n }\DIFaddend en pie, \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{basado en FES, que incluya los mÃºsculos del pie}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{como son los plantares}\DIFaddend , abdominales y de la espalda \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{, los cuales se sabe colaboran en el equilibrio de la posiciÃ³n en pie \mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
\cite{Young2003,Loram2004}}%DIFAUXCMD
. Esta mejora, incorporada a los sistemas actuales, buscarÃ­a reducir la dependencia de la andadera, al detectar eventos de desequilibrio del sujeto y efectuar acciones de control sobe los }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{\mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
\cite{Young2003,Loram2004}}%DIFAUXCMD
. Y se entiende que a mayor nÃºmero de }\DIFaddend mÃºsculos \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{para estabilizar nuevamente su posiciÃ³n en pie, para detectar estos eventos de desequilibrio, se dotarÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{incluidos en el control, se puede lograr un control que produzca movimientos mÃ}\DIFaddend ¡\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{al sistema de un lazo de retroalimentaciÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{s naturales. 
}

\DIFadd{Ã¡rbol Ã©ste podrÃ­a portÃ}\DIFaddend ³n \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{de la posiciÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{esaÃº
}

\DIFadd{Con base a lo anterior, en el presente trabajo, se propone desarrollar un FES que en conjunto con una }\textbf{\DIFadd{Unidad de mediciÃ³n inercial (IMU)}}  \DIFadd{formen un control de lazo cerrado para estimular y mantener una articulaciÃ}\DIFaddend ³n \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{del sujeto. }%DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdel{La validaciÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{en la orientaciÃ}\DIFaddend ³n \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{del sistema, se harÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{deseada. AdemÃ}\DIFaddend ¡\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{en sujetos sanos, sin SCI, de los cuales, conectados al sistema , en una posiciÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{s, aprovechando la reducciÃ}\DIFaddend ³\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{n de pie, se registrarÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{n de tamaÃ±o y consumo de la electrÃ³nica actual, se busca la creaciÃ³n de un sistema portable e inalÃ}\DIFaddend ¡\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{n los casos positivos donde el sistema fue capaz de re-estabilizarlos despuÃ}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{mbrico que pueda a futuro formar parte de un sistema mÃ¡s complejo de varios FES.
}



%DIF > TODO: EstÃ¡ bien poner los acrÃ³nimos en negritas o lo hago en itÃ¡licas?

%DIF > Esta mejora, incorporada a los sistemas actuales, buscarÃ­a reducir la dependencia de la andadera, al detectar eventos de desequilibrio del sujeto y efectuar acciones de control sobe los mÃºsculos para estabilizar nuevamente su posiciÃ³n en pie, para detectar estos eventos de desequilibrio, se dotarÃ¡ al sistema de un lazo de retroalimentaciÃ³n de la posiciÃ³n del sujeto.

%DIF > La validaciÃ³n del sistema, se harÃ¡ en sujetos sanos, sin SCI, de los cuales, conectados al sistema, en una posiciÃ³n de pie, se registrarÃ¡n los casos positivos donde el sistema fue capaz de re-estabilizarlos despuÃ©s de haber sido sometidos a una fuerza que los saque de equilibrio.

\DIFadd{Finalmente se validarÃ¡ el sistema a travÃ}\DIFaddend ©s de \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{haber sido sometidos a una fuerza que los saque de equilibrio}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{la inducciÃ³n de un Ã¡ngulo en la rodilla, donde se evaluarÃ¡ la capacidad del sistema para producir y mantener la orientaciÃ³n preestablecida}\DIFaddend .
```

When I compile I'm gettin a lot of 2 type error Unicode char and keyboard char like:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\xdef (U+206)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...estos eventos de desequilibrio, se dotar�}
>
> Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. ...l que produzca movimientos m�}\DIFaddend �

When latexdiff is running it shows a lot of times:

> Missing characters near word 90 character index: 646-649 Length: 2
>   Match: |n | (expected match marked above).
>
> tremidad como retroalimentaci├│n de la estimulaci├│n, a fin de

My preamble is:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\parindent 0em
\parskip = 2em
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\setlength{\parskip}{8pt plus 4pt minus 1pt}
%\hoffset = -0.54cm
\voffset = 0cm
\topmargin = 0cm
\headheight = 0.6cm
\topmargin = 0.5cm
\oddsidemargin =  0.5cm \evensidemargin = -0.5cm
\textwidth = 17cm



\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Familia de fuente
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
%\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm


\usepackage{cite}




% Formato de Capitulos
\usepackage[ ]{titlesec}  %
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  { \huge  \color{black}}
  {\flushright \huge \color{MidnightBlue} \textsc{ \bf \chaptertitlename } \hspace{0.1 em} { \fontsize{3cm}{1em} \color{MidnightBlue} \bf \thechapter }} {5 pt}{\bf\Large} 



%Unidades SI
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{repeatunits=false}
\DeclareSIUnit\pasos{pasos}
\sisetup{}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,range-units = single}
```

Any clue? Thanks and my best regards

Comment: This really is an answer but it is so trivial, that I do not dare to put it as actual answer: upgrade to version 1.2.0 of latexdiff, which has been released a week or so ago. You can get it for example from www.ctan.org .

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an inline argument to set the encoding.

$latexdiff --encoding=utf8 old.tex new.tex > diff.tex